# With a CTE, how do I select the rows from tableB even when tableA returns no results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e971e/10/0

So, I am running the query against two tables simultaneously. I'd like to get all info for "fran" even if she isn't in 1 table or the other. I have:

```
WITH tableA AS(
  SELECT id, name, age 
  FROM a WHERE name = 'fran'
),
tableB AS(
  SELECT id, name, address 
  FROM b WHERE name = 'fran'
)

SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name, tableA.age, tableB.address
FROM tableA, tableB

/*
WITH tableB AS(
  SELECT id, name, address 
  FROM b WHERE name = 'fran'
)

SELECT tableB.address FROM tableB
*/
```

This returns no rows even though she is in tableB (run the commented portion and it returns her address).

In the end I'd like something like:

```
id  name    age    address

--   --      --      2 Main
```

Comment: Why are you using a common table expression (CTE) rather than a simple UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your problem Marissa. The thing is that you are not joining the tables.

```
    WITH tableA AS(
      SELECT id, name, age 
      FROM a WHERE name = 'fran'
    ),
    tableB AS(
      SELECT id, name, address 
      FROM b WHERE name = 'fran'
    )

    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.age, b.address
    FROM tableA a
    FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.id = b.id
```

This will return you a row only with the address of Fran. The other attributes will be blank because you don't have the data in table A.

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all`!

```
WITH tableA AS (
      SELECT id, name, age 
      FROM a
      WHERE name = 'fran'
     ),
     tableB AS (
      SELECT id, name, address 
      FROM b
      WHERE name = 'fran'
     )
select 'a' as which, a.*
from tableA a
union all
select 'b' as which, b.*
from tableB b;
```

The `join` solutions will multiply the number of rows in the table.  So, if `a` has 3 rows and `b` has 4 rows, then the result set will have 12 rows.  With this method, the result set will have 7 rows.

Comment: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "b" Position: 258

Answer (score 1):

You need a Full Join plus Coalesce:

```
WITH tableA AS(
  SELECT id, name, age 
  FROM a WHERE name = 'fran'
),
tableB AS(
  SELECT id, name, address 
  FROM b WHERE name = 'fran'
)

SELECT COALESCE(tableA.id, tableB.id) AS id
   ,COALESCE(tableA.name, tableB.name) as name
   ,tableA.age, tableB.address
FROM tableA FULL JOIN tableB
ON tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Comment: @dfundako: Thanks for noticing, I forgot to add the CTEs

Answer (score 1):

You need a full outer join.

Based on your sqlfiddle the id is not suitable for joining (id 2 is fred in table A and fran in table B), you need to use the name column instead. You should ensure that name is indexed for proper performance.

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.name, a.age,
  b.id, b.name, b.address
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON b.name = a.name
WHERE a.name = 'fran' or b.name = 'fran'
```